# MySQL Query: Write max(Date) from whole table to each row

Tags: mysql, sql, date, max

I need to find the max(n.LastEdited) (Latest Editing Date) for my whole table and write it on each row.

What I have:

```
SELECT n.ID,
n.Title,
n.News,
(SELECT max(n.LastEdited)) AS NewsLastEdited
FROM News AS n
ORDER BY n.ID DESC
LIMIT 0,20
```

What I get (not showing ID, Title, News, ...):

```
NewsLastEdited
2012-10-25 10:54:24
2012-10-25 10:54:12
2012-10-25 10:54:02
```

What I want:

```
NewsLastEdited
2012-10-25 10:54:24
2012-10-25 10:54:24
2012-10-25 10:54:24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  n.*
FROM    news n
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  ID, Max(LastEdited) lastEdit
            FROM news
            GROUP BY ID
        ) x ON n.ID = x.ID AND 
               n.LastEdited = x.LastEdit
-- WHERE ...
-- ORDER BY ...
-- LIMIT ...
```

Comment: Please don't use [smiles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/636/187824) in posts. By the way nice solution :)

Comment: I'll try and report. Shouldn't it be `SELECT  ID, Max(LastEdited) AS lastEdit` ... ` n.LastEdited = x.lastEdit`?

Comment: can you post sample records? please. including showing ID, Title, News

Comment: `CREATE TABLE `News` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `ClassName` enum('News') CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT 'News',
  `Created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastEdited` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `News` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `BandID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `BandID` (`BandID`),
  KEY `ClassName` (`ClassName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`

Comment: I guess I got your point, try this, `SELECT n.ID,
n.Title,
n.News,
(SELECT max(LastEdited) FROM News) AS NewsLastEdited
FROM News AS n
ORDER BY n.ID DESC
LIMIT 0,20`

Comment: I don't understand ... Your answer works if I just copy and paste. But if I do some other INNER JOINS etc. I receive the same "wrong" results as before?

Comment: the new query has subquery on it `SELECT max(LastEdited) FROM News` :D

Comment: `SELECT n.ID,
           n.Title,
           n.News,
           (SELECT max(n.LastEdited)) AS NewsLastEdited,
              (SELECT Title FROM Band WHERE Band.ID = n.BandID) AS Band,
              (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM NewsKommentar WHERE NewsKommentar.NewsID = n.ID) AS Kommentaranzahl
           FROM News AS n
           INNER JOIN NewsKommentar AS k
           GROUP BY Band
           ORDER BY n.ID DESC
           LIMIT 0,20`

Comment: This query works but does show the wrong dates. Maybe you could connect your and my query? I'm still not working for a long time with databases ...

Comment: what's the purpose of this `INNER JOIN NewsKommentar AS k`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18775/discussion-between-john-woo-and-darwin)